# HTML sending input fields of a dataTable hidden in the DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am using datatable.js and I have an input field at each row.
My issue is that only the input fields of currently displayed page of the datatable get posted, I need all of them to be posted.
How can I handle it ?

I don't put any sample because I think it is not necessary here since my scenario is easy to picture and I'm after general answers.

Comment: Why would you ever need to send a field from every row?  What is the 'REAL' issue you are facing?

Comment: @briansol Thank you for your interest ! The user has a list of products that he wants to add to some entity. When he adds them, he needs to put the quantity of each product.
The most convenient way I've came up with is to put a datatable of the products, with an input field. Then he posts the form I add the products whose quantity is superior to 0, this is the context ; )
What I could do - and I do it some other page, is to put a post button on each row, and refresh the list of added products by Ajax, but I believed this new  approach would work and be more convenient for the user

Comment: A bulk replace all every time method is not a solid approach, IMO.  You should instead pass a list of SKU/Qty pairs and process it on the back end for additions to a session/cart of some sort.

Comment: The problem i guess isn't that the rows are hidden in the DOM. Datatables keeps some kind of cache and renders it when you change page.

Comment: @briansol Thanks this is what I am doing, it's not a bulk insert straight to the DB there are lots of checks but I kept these details out for clarity

Comment: @CosLu thanks ! I'll investigate I assumed it was because of that, since I'm receiving 10 entries, which is exactly the number of rows on one page.

Comment: As mentioned, datatables doesn't 'hide' anything.  it does a 'limit' on the back end and only brings back the data range requested and updates the dom with just those rows.

Comment: I guess you could use something like this http://datatables.net/api#fnGetData to read the contents of the cells you need (even the ones which aren't rendered) and maybe make an ajax post.

Answer (score 0):

I've just came accros the answer to this question accidently. I think it's not properly label in their documentation. The problem is that the the rows are not hidden, they are actually deleted from the DOM by dataTable.js to improve performance.

Lucky, the solution is simple, one needs to do this to retrieve all the input fields from a table :

```
var data = table.$('input, select').serialize();
```

On the click event of a button for example. Then the data can be sent as is in an ajax request. More details can be found [in the documentation](https://datatables.net/examples/api/form.html).

Hope this helps.